# How to create and bind control template for listview with gridview WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, gridview, listviewitem

I have code in xaml and trying create controlTemplae

```
<ListView Name="seznamSkupin" Background="White" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="#a9a9a9" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" Padding="0,30">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                     ...structure...
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource gridViewHeader}">
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NazevSkupiny }"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Data are in code behind

```
 List<Skupina> skupina = new List<Skupina>();
            string[] skupiny = {"Test", "3.A", "3.B"};
                 
            for (int i = 0; i < skupiny.Length; i++)
            {
                skupina.Add(new Skupina() { NazevSkupiny = skupiny[i]});
            }

            seznamSkupin.ItemsSource = skupina;
```

It works in xaml, but I need to create template for listView, - I have two listViews and nedd to use same styles. I am using separate style.xaml, trying this, but content of "seznamSkupin" is not showed:

```
<Style x:Key="dialogListView" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                    <ListView Background="{StaticResource color3}" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0,30">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource fontFamilyDefault}" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource fontSize3}" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource color5 }" />
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12,0"/>
                                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />

                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                                            <Border CornerRadius="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  
                                              BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"   
                                              BorderBrush="Black"   
                                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                
                                                >
                                                <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="0,3,0,3" BorderBrush="white" Padding="0,3" >


                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <GridViewRowPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Columns="{TemplateBinding GridView.ColumnCollection}" />
                                                    </Grid>

                                                </Border>
                                            </Border>
                                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource color1}" />
                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource color4}" />
                                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                                </Trigger>
                                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </ListView>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I think, problem is in `GridViewRowPresenter` can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: A template of a `ListView` should not contain another `ListView`. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I haven´t `ListView` in another `ListView`. Just two separate `ListView` in same xaml and I want style them via template. Or is my template wrong and represent `ListView` in `ListView`? I´m new in wpf... Thanks

Comment: Yes, your template shouldn't include a `ListView` element.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I didn´t know, that `ItemContainerStyle` can be set separately in `ListView` head.